# ng-repeat not updating using $scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I need some help in displaying the results of an update in my ng-repeat directive from $watch

- ProductsCtrl is watching for a change of product type and when it detects one it searches for Products of that type.
- This definitely detects the product type change and I'm getting results back from the updateProducts function but the products I get back are not displayed.
- I thought mapping the $scope.productService.products to ProductService.products would mean it would be updated automatically.

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('ProductsCtrl',['$scope','ProductService', '$location', 'SessionDataService',    function($scope, ProductService, $location, SessionDataService){

  $scope.productService = ProductService;
  $scope.productService.products = ProductService.products;
  $scope.sessionDataService = SessionDataService;
  $scope.productType = SessionDataService.productType;

  $scope.$watch('productType', function(productTypeNew, productTypeOld){
      //update products
        console.log('ProductsCtrl: watch : New Val - '+ productTypeNew + ',     Old Val - ' + productTypeOld);
        $scope.productService.updateProducts(productTypeNew);
        console.log("ProductsCtrl: watch : Products retrieved - " +         $scope.productService.products);        
}, true);

}]);
```

**services.js**

```
.factory('Product',['$resource', function($resource){
return $resource('/products/:id', {
    id: '@id'
});
}])
.factory('ProductService', ['Product', function(Product){
var products = [];

function updateProducts(productType){
    console.log("ProductService updateProducts with product type " + productType);
        Product.query({product_type: productType},
        function (data) {
            console.log("ProductService updateProducts returned " + data);
              var retProducts = data;
              angular.copy(retProducts, products);
              //console.log(retProducts);
            });
}
return {

    products: products,
    updateProducts: updateProducts

}}])
```

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="ProductsCtrl">
        <tr ng-repeat="product in productService.products">
            <td>{{product.title}}</td>
            <td>{{product.retailler}}</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this or someone can explain why - the answer was to encapsulate the whole table element in the controller and not just the ng-repeat

**Solution:**

```
<div ng-controller="ProductsCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Retailler</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
            <td>{{product.title}}</td>
            <td>{{product.retailler}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like `console.log(retProducts);` does print the new values, but your screen doesn't refresh. I think this is because your copy code is in $apply, so there was not $digest after your copy. I would wrap your angular.copy in an $apply:

```
.factory('ProductService', ['Product', '$rootScope', function(Product){
var products = [];

function updateProducts(productType){
    console.log("ProductService updateProducts with product type " + productType);
        Product.query({product_type: productType},
        function (data) {$rootScope.$apply(function() {
            console.log("ProductService updateProducts returned " + data);
              var retProducts = data;
              angular.copy(retProducts, products);
              //console.log(retProducts);
            })});
}
return {

    products: products,
    updateProducts: updateProducts

}}])
```

Comment: Thanks - I did try this earlier and I'm getting a Error: $digest already in progress

Comment: @createsomevalue Sad. Can you console.log(products) after the angular.copy? Does it look right?

Comment: @createsomevalue Also, I would install Batarang (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) to see if your scope actually changed.

Comment: Batarang looks really useful. I have the same architecture in place for another part of the app and it works find. The only difference is I'm updating within the $watch for this. Using batarang I can see the products in AngularJS Properties so I have no idea why they are not displayed.

Comment: I've worked out why this is happening. The ng-controller='ProductsCtrl' needed to encapsulate the whole table element and not just the results. Will post the answer when I'm allowed.